# Blocking unwanted elements/frames at dailymail.co.uk with uBlock Origin

Tags: ublock-origin

This started as a pet peave but now it's an academic exercise.

Occasionally I follow a link to a story at the UK's Daily Mail and I want to write a rule/filter for uBlockO to prevent my eyes being soiled by the tawdry, sycophantic sidebar stories that invariably litter the right-hand margin of the page. uBlockO's "block element" function works well enough but only for that one specific element. I want to block the entire category.

Here is a (redacted) example URL:

```
www.dailymail.co.uk/tvshowbiz/article-1234567/abcd-efgh-ijkl-mnop.html
```

When I "block element" it, the filter it creates is this:

```
www.dailymail.co.uk##a[href="/tvshowbiz/article-1234567/abcd-efgh-ijkl-mnop.html"] > .pufftext > strong
```

I've tried every permutation I can think of to block everything from `www.dailymail.co.uk/tvshowbiz/article-* outward`, or even `www.dailymail.co.uk/tvshowbiz/*`, but none of them have any effect. I don't know if I'm using the wrong uBlock function or if my syntax is in error.

Any clues?

Comment: You just need to block the entire div where the advertisements are. The filter would look like this `www.dailymail.co.uk##.beta`

Comment: Thank you for the reply, DrZoo, but these aren't adverts, they're links to other stories/articles at the Daily Mail.  And I'm afraid I don't know what a "div" is.  As a guess, I did try www.dailymail.co.uk##.tvshowbiz but it had no effect.

Comment: Not understanding basic HTML is probably why you're having trouble blocking what you want. Here is a picture [with the div](https://imgur.com/a/gZAda). Here is a picture [without the div](https://imgur.com/a/fZNCK). I quickly blocked the whole thing to show the difference. I was unclear what you exactly wanted blocked.

Answer (score 0):

I'll go you one better.  I didn't even know 'div' ***was*** HTML.

I appreciate your help but while I was trying to figure out which 'div' to block, I found that I'd have got the result I wanted in the first place if I'd been more thorough when investigating the "block element" function.  I needed to paint with a broader brush so I was selecting the greater frame rather than one of the elements contained within the frame.  When I hit the right spot, the filter it created was:

www.dailymail.co.uk##.lead-alpha.cleared:nth-of-type(3) > .beta

And that produced the same result you posted images of.  The entire frame disappears.

Thanks again!